# CodeIgniter deploy in Google Cloud

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed CodeIgniter framework in Google Cloud app engine. But when I am trying to access website it is showing 404. I have attached screenshot of file structure .

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
runtime: php55
threadsafe: yes
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /user_guide/
  static_files: user_guide/index.html
  upload: user_guide/index.html

- url: /user_guide/(.*)
  static_files: user_guide/\1
  upload: user_guide/(.*)

- url: /static/(.*)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*)

- url: .*
  script: index.php

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.bak$
```

Comment: I guess that's your suggested replacement app.yaml? Can you explain what changes you've made vs the one on display? Some of them, e.g. special routes for /user_guide/, don't look like they're useful to the OP.